# Regular expression grammar & NFAs

Tags: regex, expression, nfa

```
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*
```

I have the above regular expression. To my understanding:

the first letter must be 'a to z' uppercase/lowercase and the rest of the letters must be 'a to z' uppercase/lowercase and/or digits.

So,

```
aJoieri_ => valid
7aaaG => invalid
a^ghr => invalid
AsS_ => valid
```

Am I correct? Also, to turn that expression into an NFA (replacing all letters with label 'letter', and replacing all digits with label 'digit') - would my NFA diagram be complete, or is it incorrect?

[image: My NFA Diagram]

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I'd add is that regular expressions will try to match your patterns anywhere in the string, unless you add anchors ("^" or "\A" for beginning of line or string, and "$" or "\z" for end of line or string).  So

```
aJoieri_ => valid and matches aJoieri_
7aaaG => valid matches aaaG
a^ghr => valid matches ghr
AsS_ => valid matches AsS_
```